# serialization symbol \" from Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

When I serialize String element with `\"` inside, result is `"{\"role\":\"student\", \"userType\":\"techer\"}"` How to change result to `"{"role":"student", "userType":"techer"}"`? Used java, jackson lib.

```
        String value = "{\"role\":\"student\", \"userType\":\"techer\"}";
        System.out.println(value); //{"role":"student", "userType":"techer"}
        
        String json2 = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(value);
        System.out.println(json2);// "{\"role\":\"student\", \"userType\":\"techer\"}"
```

Comment: If your `value` is already JSON, why are you trying to serialize it as a JSON string? What you're trying to do makes no sense.

Comment: yourString.replaceAll("\\\\", "");

Comment: @MarkRotteveel because it a feature of my project. I have a Map<String,String> and I need set Object (String view) to value map.